# ansible task to unarchive a zip file without a first level directory using "extra_opt: -j" fails in Centos7.5 servers and works in Centos7.3

Tags: ansible

I have an ansible-role which has a task to unarchive a .zip file without the first-level directory.

Ansible-task:

```
- name: Cryptography support - download & unarchive jce_policy-8.zip
  unarchive:
    extra_opts: -j
    src: https://###.nexus.###.com/repository/oracle_jdk/java/jce/8/jce_policy-8.zip
    dest: "{{java_cryptography_path}}"
    remote_src: yes
  tags:
    - cryptography
```

where,

```
{{java_cryptography_path}}= /usr/java/default/jre/lib/security/
```

This fails on Centos7.5 servers which are on azure cloud instances but is successful on Centos7.3 servers which are on openstack cloud instances

This was the verbose warning

```
The full traceback is:
WARNING: The below traceback may *not* be related to the actual failure.
  File "/tmp/ansible_unarchive_payload_KHaxre/ansible_unarchive_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/basic.py", line 1071, in selinux_context
    ret = selinux.lgetfilecon_raw(to_native(path, errors='surrogate_or_strict'))
```

Could someone please help me on this. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried it without the `-j` switch? Maybe an update of ansible helps?

Comment: My ansible and python versions: ```ansible: 2.7.9 and python: 3.7.3```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue after debugging. Thought it might be helpful to share it for people who come across similar issues.

It is how `ansible unarchive.py` module is written. Since the remote servers I was trying to configure has `selinux: enabled`, tt was failing. All we need to do is just disable it temporarily or permanently as per your organization rules.

There is an example task in ansible documentation for that. docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/selinux_module.html

We should also `reboot` the system once `selinux is disabled`. There are examples in ansible documentation for that too, docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/reboot_module.html